# Best solution for a loop inside of a loop in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

For example:

```
result=[]
todolist=mongo.db.Todo.find()
for todo in todolist:
    for detail in todo['list']:
        result.append(str(detail))
```

I'm looking for the best way of avoiding nested for loops.
I'm a newbie.
Who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your nested loops?

Comment: Do you something like list comprehension as `result = [str(detail) for todo in todolist for detail in todo['list']]`?

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer since you said you don't want to use `for` loops.

Comment: I mean I want to avoid nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for as the 'best way for a loop inside of a loop':

```
results = [str(detail) for todo in todolist for detail in todo['list']]
```

To convert that to json:

```
import json

json_result = json.dumps(results)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered a for loop?